# How to create symbolic link to a file that is not shared in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts

I am trying to create shared shortcut to a file that is not shared.  Is there a solution?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: A Symbolic Link is not the same as a Shortcut.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Microsoft_Windows) for the differences.  How are you attempting to create this link/shortcut? What have you tried so far?